# Inner Join query Not Working inside JPA custom query

Tags: mysql, jpa

> I want to perform Inner Join query With JPA Custom query, When I
> Define Inner Join query Inside @Query() it throw an unExcepted result.
> When I write same query in side MYSQL yog editor this query works fine
> ,There is no issue. But issue generate with JPA
> In my database table Organization store address_id as foreign key  .
> address_id column name generate automatically,No where I define
> address_id in my entity class. When I fire inner join query by calling
> organization.address=Address.id  shows below type of error

```
Type mismatch: com.nilmani.onetooneunidirectional.entiry.Address type is expected
```

> Here is the query
> organizationRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.onetooneunidirectional.repository

import com.nilmani.onetooneunidirectional.entiry.Organization
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

interface OrganizationRepository : JpaRepository<Organization,Long> {
    @Query("SELECT Organization .id,Organization .name,Address .building,Address .city FROM  Organization INNER JOIN Address WHERE Organization.address =Address .id")
    fun findSomeRelationalFeatures()
}
```

> Organization.kt

```
package com.nilmani.onetooneunidirectional.entiry

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
data class Organization(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    var name:String="",
    var orgId:String="",
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Address::class,cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var address: Address
)
```

> Address.kt

```
package com.nilmani.onetooneunidirectional.entiry

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class Address(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val building:String="",
    val street:String="",
    val city:String="",
    val state:String="",
    val country:String="",
    val zipCode:String=""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select o from Organization o inner join fetch o.address
```